# Intel XDK, geolocation based

Tags: javascript, cordova, augmented-reality, intel-xdk, wikitude

I'm trying to implement an augmented reality application in which we can visualize elements by using the camera device in background.
I have to implement this feature only by using javascript (and cordova). In cordova, I can only use the camera application itself, not just a preview and the HTML methods are not sufficient... so I've searched for other things.

I've found first wikitude. The problem was that it's not free, and too complicated.
I'm disappointed because it was perfect in the method of integration (simple plugin of cordova to add etc... and use it as a simple plugin like compass, geolocation etc...)

After that, I've found an other thing: intel xdk. But the problem is that I have to install the intel xdk on the computer directly, use an other software to develop the code. If we could just use a thing like:

```
<script src="something_to_use_directly_intel_xdk_without.js"></script>
```

And after that the common method:

```
intel.xdk.display.startAR();
```

But the problem, as said before is that I can't use directly this framework in the javascript files, in the manner of wikitude or a simple import.

So here I am, trying to use a simple plugin or something like this just to display the camera preview in background. And the only things to do were to add elements on this background easily computed by using the accelerometer, compass and geolocation plugins of cordova.

So, if you have any ideas (simple ideas just to display the camera in background!!), it would be very helpful. So if you have any suggestions please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get started with Wikitude, there is a sample application inside the SDK package with source code for Android and iOS you can use as a starting point and you can request a trial licence to set up your project.

Moreover, if you already use cordova, Wikitude also has a PhoneGap plugin (on GitHub: https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap).

Comment: Thank for your answer. But with wikitude I can't use the plugin without using the trial version (which displays a "trial" text in the middle of the string I think) and this is not my goal.